# Enforce only pull request on visual studio team services

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

There is any way I could enforce that some people could contribute by one branch only by pull request I want them to be able to accept pull request but not to direct push changes.

This would be useful because we have some branch polices in place that for someone to accept a pull request for example the build must pass. The problem is if we allow someone to accept pull request we would be allowing them to push direct to the branch. There it is any way to give permissions to a branches to only receive changes trough pull request, or at least give permissions to someone to only accept pull requests but not to push directly to the branch.

I need to do that on visual studio online.

What I need it is to remove the permission of someone to direct push commits to a branch without a pull request.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The UI has changed since this question has been asked, the feature is still there:

[image]

Yes this is possible with the last release of Visual Studio Online by setting a Git Branch Policy:

> ### Branch policies
>
> To help teams using Git improve the quality of code going into their repo, we’ve added a new capability to set policies on branches. These new policies enable teams to configure requirements for their development branches that are enforced by the server when pushing or merging pull requests. Build breaks can be prevented by using the build policy to require that all changes entering a branch pass a configured build.
>
> [image: Setting branch pull request policies]
>
> Code review policies can be used to set a minimum number of reviewers for pull requests, or even require specific users to review changes made to specific portions of your codebase.
>
> [image: Setting code review requirements]

<sub>https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-may-15-vso</sub>

Comment: This actually don't solve the problem with this the person still able to merge direct to the branch and push commits directly to it without the use of a pull request.

Comment: if you check the "Require code reviews using pull request", then direct commits will not be allowed. It may be that Project Admins (who have the force push permission by default) are allowed to bypass this policy, I haven't checked. By setting the minimum reviewers to 1 and allowing a person to accept their own request, you're effectively enforcing the build to succeed and allow a person to them commit their own PR.

Comment: Thank you a lot jesse just tested and worked perfectly

Comment: If you are lost in the visualstudio unfriendly interface (like me), this link might help: http://techtwaddle.net/tag/vsovisual-studio-onlinebranch-policy/

Comment: I am using TFS online I have options for branch policies but not an option for Require code reviews using pull requests, any ideas?

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing caught me out last night but  I checked "minimum number of reviewers per pull request" and it stopped me from pushing directly to the master branch as I wanted. Seems strange though as the wording sounds like it will only stop you from completing a pull request without x number of approvers and not stop the direct push.

Comment: Yeah... Well... That;s what it is.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that must be set:

1. Set a Policy on the branch(es) you want protected, the simplest is to set "Require a minimum number of reviewers".  See [Microsoft Git Branch Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies)
2. Ensure that Contributors are set not to be exempt from policy enforcement - [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gXni.png)

Comment: "Ensure that Contributors are set not to be exempt from policy enforcement" - This line is really important, as all the policies won't do anything without this permission denied.