# Branch policies for a specific folder in VSO

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

[I know how to enable branch policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936622/enforce-only-pull-request-on-visual-studio-team-services) but what I need is enforcing branch policies only on a specific folder.

Our repo is a messed up collection of "drivers", as a first step towards separating it to several independent repos we want to enable access to one folder to specific team and leave the rest intact (pushing directly to master...), the most straightforward solution looks like setting up branch policies and requiring pull requests.

Unfortunately this is only enabled on a per-branch.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Git works. How can you enforce permissions on a single folder when anyone who clones the repository has access to the entirety of the repository? The most granular permission you can control is at the branch level, and even then, you can't restrict what people do with a branch locally -- you can only control it when they try to push changes.

Comment: Well I want to limit pushes the master, I don't care about people seeing or changing the code locally. And yes, I am aware that this is not the way we should work,  this is just a temporary fix.